# Change a Dynamic Link's Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the color of a link, which is created on runtime.

CSS Code:

```
a{  
   color:  #0C6A13;
}
```

The problem with this code is, it only changes those static links created before the document is loaded.

JavaScript Code:

```
 $( "a" ).on( "load", function() {

     this.color = #0C6A13;
 });
```

I also use this code but it doesnt work.

Comment: $( "a" ).on( "change", function() {
     $(this).css("color", "#0C6A13");
 });

Comment: From the jQuery API documentation: _The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object._

Comment: There's no such thing as an anchor tag being "loaded".

Comment: The CSS should be enough, unless you have some other style rule overwriting it. Inspect the element in your browser dev tools (F12) and check it.

Comment: @MelanciaUK--> Thank you so much. Im sorry if this is a dumb question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check you `load()` handler first, is it getting called or not because there is no such a thing to determine that particular element is loaded, You can set style attributes at the time of element generation, though you can try this:

```
this.style.color = "#0C6A13";
```

OR

```
$(this).css("color","#0C6A13");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do that:

```
$("a").on("click", function(){

  $(this).css("color", "gray");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this states of `<a>` tag to your css stylesheet

```
    a:link
    a:visited
    a:active
    a:hover
```